# symfony user roles and class diagram

Tags: symfony, diagram, class-diagram

suppose we have a symfony project with 3 roles ( role_user, role_admin, role_superadmin) where the super admin can promote a user to be an admin or depromote him back to a user state.
The question is in a class diagram, will these roles  be presented by 3 classes or we gonna have just one class "User" with a "role" attribute ?

Comment: What does your instructor suggest?

Comment: i don't have an instructor

Comment: It really depends on the project you're working on, but the basic and fastest way is to have a property "roles" on your class User, cause the @security() annotation works by default by checking your user provider model "roles" attribute in you User class.

Answer (score 0):

It will be one class User with a role string attribute.